# how to calculate in select statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Work on C# linq entity framework 4.

Want to avoid foreach loop from my bellow syntax .Is it capable to calculate foreach loop calculation in select statement?

```
var result = (from p in MasterDetail
              join q in Master on p.TaxID equals q.TaxID
              where p.EffectiveDate >= tempEffectiveDate && p.EffectiveDate <= tempEffectiveDate
              select new TransactionItem
              {
                  MasterDetailID = p.MasterDetailID,
                  CustomCode = p.CustomCode,
                  TaxID = p.TaxID,
                  TaxName = q.TaxName,
                  ItemID = p.ItemID,
                  EffectiveDate = p.EffectiveDate,
                  SlavAmount = (decimal)0.0,
                  SlavTaxAmount = (decimal)0,
                  Rate = p.Rate,
                  BarCode = p.BarCode,
                  IsPercentage = p.IsPercentage,
                  CurrencyID = p.CurrencyID,
                  MinAmount = p.MinAmount,
                  MaxAmount = p.MaxAmount,
              }).AsEnumerable();


decimal tempgivenAmount = givenAmount;
decimal temp = 0;
List<TransactionItem> oList = new List<MasterDetailList>();


foreach (MasterDetailList item in result)
{
    temp = tempgivenAmount - item.MaxAmount;

    if (temp >= 0)
    {
        temp = item.MaxAmount;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = tempgivenAmount;
    }

    if (item.IsPercentage == true)
    {
        item.SlavTaxAmount = (decimal)Math.Abs(temp) * (item.Rate / 100);
    }
    else
    {
        item.SlavTaxAmount = item.Rate;
    }

    item.SlavAmount = Math.Abs(temp);
    tempgivenAmount = tempgivenAmount - item.MaxAmount;
    oList.Add(item);

    if (tempgivenAmount <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I write the above foreach using LINQ?

Comment: Why do you not want the foreach loop? Linq isn't a replacement for standard coding, it's a helper. Nothing wrong with using standard foreach loop IMO.

Comment: Psytronic,thanks .If it’s possible to avoid loop ,then why are we using loop .Need to use this syntax several times and need to increase my query performance .avoiding the loop think will increase my query performance.

Comment: @shamim LINQ expressions also loop elements. If you need to perform an action on every element you need a loop, that is independent on if you use LINQ or a foreach or a for

Comment: based on your comment, what exactly is it that you are trying to solve? Why do you believe that a LINQ expression would solve your performance issues? What performance issues are we talking about here? Have you investigated what exactly is the culprit? I do not believe that exchanging a foreach with a LINQ would increase performance (I actually think it could get worse)

Comment: Default,thanks for your valuable comments.Is it possible calculation in select statement like in sql select statement sub-query.Default if it's worse ,will you please tell me why it's worse.

Comment: LINQ to EF will NOT convert arbitrary code to valid SQL aggregation statements. It will either throw an exception or extract all values to the client and then apply the aggregation.

EF is an ORM, not a way to bypass proper SQL. If you want to increase performance, create a view that will return the values you want together with the appropriate indexes. No indexes, no performance improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional expressions aren't hard to use inside a LINQ query; just use the `? :` conditional operator. And you can even introduce temporary variables using the `let` keyword.

But I think your remaining-balance accumulator (`tempgivenAmount`) would be a sticking point. Each loop iteration, you're decrementing that value by some calculated amount, and then that new value becomes an input to the next iteration's calculations. LINQ isn't built to use mutable variables like that; it's designed for pure functional operations with no side effects. (If you're using LINQ to Objects, you can get away with some mutability, but those constructs wouldn't map to SQL so you couldn't use them with Entity Framework.)

Given the way your calculation works, I think you need your loop to happen in code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but non-SQL functions don't always work inside a LINQ-2-SQL query, like `Math.Abs()`.

Comment: This is Entity Framework, but they still don't work - or if they don't cause an exception, they will force an Enumeration the query and run on the generated result.

Comment: Entity Framework does support some functions, and I'd be awfully surprised if `Math.Abs` wasn't supported. But I haven't checked.